# Efficient Data Structure to Save on Disk

Tags: python, performance, file, data-structures

I am working with many datasets that are of the structure Key|Date|Value.
The Key values can be variable length strings, or integers. The value can be any date type. The dates can be non continuous. An example set might be:

ABC|12-Dec-2021|1.0

DE|21-Dec-2022|5.0

HIJGSDFSDF|13-Dec-2021|1.0

ABC|15-Dec-2021|5.0

In general there can be ~5000 dates and ~20000 identifiers for each dataset. I am trying to store this on disk, so that can be loaded into Python into Numpy arrays efficiently. The modes of access could be:

1. Return all Key, Dates and Values from a file
2. Return all Dates and Values for a given list of Key
3. Return all Values, for an input list of Keys and Dates (maintaining order of inputs). The date lookup can be fuzzy, with lookback and tolerance - e.g. return the most recent value within 10 days

The focus is on fast read speed - writing can be slower.

My idea so far is to lay the file out like:
a) Header information including data types etc
b) Array of Unique Keys, and Offset into the file for Data
c) At each offset, Store (Date, Value) pairs sorted in date order

All reads would be based on a memory map of the file. The three reads would then look like:

1. Read all keys from b), calculate size of required array from offsets and data size, then allocate the three arrays for Key/Date/Value and iterate through the file and copy across to each array
2. Same as 1, but filter the array of keys based on input
3. First sort the Key and Date arrays, then iterate through and for each Key, move to the offset, and perform a binary search for each date to get the value. Once this has been complete, perform another sort to take it back to the original order.

I am wondering if there are better data structures or approaches to this problem.

Edit: Have considered a database, e.g. SQLITE, however do not believe this is performant for read type 3. E.g. If my input key array was (a,b,a,a,b,b) and date array was (11-Nov, 11-Nov,13-Nov,12-Nov,12-Nov,15-Nov), the SQL query would need to: Build a where clause for each unique pair of key/date, extract this, then sort again.
In addition, the lookback would require even more complexity, as if there as no a,11-Nov pair, but there was a a,5-Nov pair, this should be returned.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a small sqlite database to me

Comment: `sqlite` or `dbm` https://pymotw.com/3/dbm/index.html

Comment: ... both are built-in https://pymotw.com/3/sqlite3/index.html

Comment: Re the edit: That can be done with a temporary table holding all searched keys

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I use 'Parquet" to improve on disk storage and read times.

https://www.rstudio.com/blog/speed-up-data-analytics-with-parquet-files/